# PayPal - billing address with BuyNow button

Tags: paypal, billing

I am a bit lost in the PayPal world now, and can't beleive that just to obtain proper billing address, I can't use the super-simple BuyNow button thing anymore.

Is there any easy way to get billing address along with the minimal information that I get from PayPal? I have found the list of parameters I can pass in HTML Variables, but looks like billing info, like VAT number is not there.

Any ideas..?

Comment: Why do want a billing address? This is not intended as a flip question, but to understand what you would need from PayPal. Normally "billing address" is the address at which a credit card's monthly bills are delivered, which a merchant collects from a payer and passes to the payment processor so the processor can check it & reduce fraud (assuming the billing address is a secret only the cardholder would have). PayPal doesn't have or use this concept in their fraud prevention so... what do you need/why do you need it? Maybe PayPal has something yu can use, maybe not....

Comment: Because for accounting reasons I need to issue a proper bill for every income.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the benefits of using PayPal for buyers is that they don't have to share billing info with all the different sellers they're buying from.  As such, PayPal will provide a shipping address (when applicable) but not a billing address.  If the address PayPal is returning for you isn't sufficient you'll have to build your own form to collect that info prior to sending the user to PayPal for payment.